# Azure Data Studio (formerly SQL Operations Studio) Chart Results

Tags: azure-data-studio

The chart function in Azure Data Studio produces a chart for the following query (under Results > Charts ) when really I want just a simple line chart of run time over time. Seems like the chart results feature in Azure Data Studio does not allow you to fix auto-generate charts?

[image]

```
SELECT run_dt, run_time FROM
(VALUES
('2018-12-19', '42'),
('2018-12-18', '84'),
('2018-12-17', '53'),
('2018-12-14', '58'),
('2018-12-14', '60')
) AS etl_log(run_dt, run_time);
```

Comment: I guess the charting function in Azure Data Studio just doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

It does look like it's broken -- specifically missing a parameter.

I found the following workaround to help:

1. Change the parameter Chart Type to "bar".
2. Change the (now-visible) parameter Data Direction to "Vertical".
3. Change the parameter Chart Type back to "line".

Comment: Still broken after two years.